# How to handle Exception in controller for Spring Boot REST API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am confused of how I should handler the exception of the controller in a Spring Boot Rest API. Right now I throw some exception in my service classes like this:

```
public Optional<Item> getSpecificItem(Long itemId) throws Exception {

    return Optional.ofNullable(itemRepository.findById(itemId).
            orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Item with that id doesn't exist")));
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to do it but it kind of works, I am open to criticism. For the controller classes I don't know how it should look, I saw some example with @ControllerAdvice and exception for each controller and that looked kind of bad to me. Can I have a global exception class for all controllers? Is it good practice ?

Saw some examples and I don't know if they were the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ControllerAdvice` is good if you not use for general Exception. Example, if you define spec exception such as `SkyIsRedException`. So, it will be throw anywhere it will catch.

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExampleAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(SkyIsRedException.class)
    @ResponseCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) // <- not required
    public void methodName1() { ... }

    @ExceptionHandler(SkyIsGreenException.class)
    public void methodName2() { ... }

}
```

And you can this `@ExceptionHandler` in controller too, so it will activate if any methods of controller will throw this `SkyIsRedException`.

I not recommend use `Exception` for everything. You are only harming yourself.

---

**UPDATE:**

```java
// annotations
public class Controller {

    // annotations
    public Optional<Item> getSpecificItem(Long itemId) throws ItemNotExistException {
        return Optional.ofNullable(itemRepository.findById(itemId).
            orElseThrow(() -> new ItemNotExistException("Item with that id doesn't exist")));
    }

    // Controller specific exception handler, not central like @ControllerAdvice
    @ExceptionHandler(ItemNotExistException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public String itemNotExistExceptionHandler(ItemNotExistException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage(); // example
    {

}
```

Comment: So when I should use Exception, in what situations?

Comment: In my controller package, I normally have a *ControllerAdvice* class, nice to handle all exceptions in one place. By default you should just add an Exception catcher in there as well and perhaps return a responce code of 500.

Comment: A nice exception for "Item with that id doesn't exist" is called `NoSuchElementException`. And you can specify subcategories, such as `ItemNotExistException extends NoSuchElementException`. And you handle this exception. So, you can separate error handling. I have modified the original answer.